# Use multiple lines javascript in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have this source code, in `React` function component

```
return (
  result.map(item => (
    <tr key={item.id}>
      <td>
      {new Date(item.pub_date).getFullYear()} /
      {new Date(item.pub_date).getMonth()} /
      {new Date(item.pub_date).getDate()}
      </td>
    </tr>
```

However in this script, it require three `Date` instances.

I want to shorten like this.

```
var date = new Date(item.pub_date)
date.getFullYear() / date.getMonth() /date.getDate()
```

Is it correct idea? or is it impossible to this in JSX??

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want with a little different way with the use of template literals and setting date variable outside of the return scope.

```
return (
  result.map(item => {
    const date = new Date(item.pub_date)

    return (
      <tr key={item.id}>
        <td>
        {`${date.getFullYear()} / ${date.getMonth()} / ${date.getDate()}`}
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a seperate function for formatting date:

```
function getDate(dateValue){
     let date = new Date(dateValue);
     return `${date.getFullYear()} / ${date.getMonth()} / ${date.getDate()}`
    }

return (
  result.map(item => {
    return (
      <tr key={item.id}>
        <td>
        {getDate(item.pub_date)}
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  })
)
```